# localStorage not saving correctly

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to save checked list items into an array and save to localStorage, it works great if you check first item down the line in order. But if you check any other item besides the first, say the second or third item, only the first item gets saved to local storage. I need to be able to save whatever item was clicked, not always position [0] of the list items.

The code below saves everything into position [0] of the array. So clicking first item will work since its in position [0], but clicking the second item also saves position [0] instead of position [1].

```
const savedChecks;
const myArr = [];

savedChecks = document.querySelector('.saved-list-item').innerHTML;
myArr.push(savedChecks);

localStorage.setItem('checkItems'+ new Date().getTime(), JSON.stringify(myArr);
```

So then I tried this, but this code gives the same result, saves at position [0] only, but expected to since ive added the [0], but thought maybe looping through the keys would display all at position [0]:

```
localStorage.setItem('checkItems'+ new Date().getTime(), JSON.stringify([...myArr][0]);
```

Im looping thru the localStorage and displaying the result like so:

```
for(let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    if(localStorage !== null) {
        document.querySelector('#savedList').innerHTML += JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)));
    }
}
```

Comment: you've declared savedChecks and myArr both as constants. you cannot initialize them later.

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll()` to get all the elements that match the selector.

```
let savedItems = document.querySelectorAll('.saved-list-item');
let myArr = Array.from(savedItems).map(el => el.innerHTML);
localStorage.setItem('checkItems'+ new Date().getTime(), JSON.stringify(myArr);
```

And make sure the selector only matches the checked items. You could use event listeners to add and remove another class on the items when they're checked and unchecked, then select that.

Comment: This code almost did the job, it saves the correct checked item, but it also saves the unchecked items too (saves whole list). I think it is in my html/EJS code, I will work with it to see if I can make your code work.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the helpful comments here, I see what I was doing wrong and here is the final solution to solve this issue if anyone else ever sees this problem. I've labeled the edits.

```
let savedChecks;
let myArr = [];

savedChecks = document.querySelectorAll('.saved-list-item'); /*<--Here use querySelectorAll as stated by others in the comments*/

savedChecks = savedChecks[i].innerHTML; /*<-- Here loop through the savedChecks */

myArr.push(savedChecks);

localStorage.setItem('checkItems'+ new Date().getTime(), JSON.stringify(myArr));
```

Comment: Where is the loop? Where are you testing whether the item is checked?